# In Umbraco 7.13, I need a way to get a nodes URL

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to get a node's URL in Umbraco.

I want to do this from a custom class called by a webservice, to automatically send emails containing every nodes URL.

Usually i use this method

```
 using umbraco.NodeFactory;
 ...
 Node node = new Node(1234);
 string link = node.Url;
```

But this is returning an error that the reference to umbracoContext cant be null.

As I understand it from around the web, this is caused because a cron job is calling this service, then umbracoContext is null.

I need a way to get the url of a node, by giving the nodes Id.

I have tried all of these methods, all of them returning the same error:

```
 string url = umbraco.library.NiceUrl(1234);


 var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext);
 string url  = umbracoHelper.Url(1234);


 var objectNode = umbracoHelper.TypedMedia(1234);
 string url = objectNode.Url;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, you shouldn't be using the Node API in V7, it's VERY old and has been deprecated. Same for umbraco.library!

An easy way to do this would be to create a WebAPI controller endpoint on the Umbraco site that gets the URLs of every page on the site and returns them as an array of URLs. You can add authentication etc to it if you wish to make it secure. The documentation for WebAPI controllers can be found below:

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

Your WebAPI controller will have a full UmbracoContext available and access to the Umbraco helper, so you can have something broadly like this:

```
public class AlertController : UmbracoApiController
{
    public List<string> GetAllUrls()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        var allContent = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().FirstOrDefault().DescendantsOrSelf();

        foreach (var page in allContent)
        {
            list.Add(page.Url);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to do things like filter out content you don't want, or that doesn't need to be listed (e.g. settings nodes).

Your other service can then call the webAPI endpoint and consume the list of URLs and use that to send the emails.